# MSI build executing the install wizard -exe file in SYSTEM mode

Tags: msbuild, windows-installer, manifest

In visual studio installer project in C++, It created a msi file using some dependencies and executable files(In my case -InstallWizard.exe) and InstallWizard.exe file generated in another visual studio project with project configuration of only run/execute under administrator level.

But When I build and executing msi file with that InstallWizard.exe file, the generated msi file invoking the InstallWizard.exe file in SYSTEM user mode. How can I change that configuration to only run under admin mode and not on system mode?